# How to change expiration date using eclipse ADT while signing android app?

Tags: android

i am signing my app using eclipse ADT..But i couldn't see any facility to change the expiration date of the key for the desired app..At the end i got a message telling that "the expiration date will expire on April 2012.But android market support only apps with expiration date 2033.How can i change expiration date using eclipse ADT ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the expiration date of the signing certificate. You need to generate a new one. If you have already published an application, you will not be able to update it with the new certificate, you will have to re-publish it with a new package.